# Values retained during post back in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

Suppose i have a model with a validation

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="ID not entered")]
    [StringLength(5,ErrorMessage = "Length should be 5")]
    public string Id { get; set; }




}
```

In the view page i have a text box. When the validation fails. The controller returns to the view page with error message.

```
public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel lg)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }
        return View();

    }
```

**But the text box contains the previous values. How does it retains the value? And is there any way to avoid it?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to delete the data just try the link which rattlemouse has posted -

```
ModelState.Clear()
```

or you do it manually with

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel lg)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

        }
       else{
             lg.Id = string.Empty;
             return View(lg);
        }

    }
```

Comment: even without passing the model, its retaining the value. But is there any way to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Clear ModelState and return view without model.

```
  ModelState.Clear();
  return View();
```

**ModelState**

[Controller.ModelState Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.modelstate(v=vs.118).aspx)

> ModelState is a property of a Controller, and can be accessed from those classes that inherit from System.Web.Mvc.Controller. The ModelState represents a collection of name and value pairs that were submitted to the server during a POST. It also contains a collection of error messages for each value submitted.